# Eloquent ORM: Select as excerpt

Tags: sql, select, orm, eloquent

I'd like to perform the following select statement using Eloquent ORM:

```
SELECT LEFT(title, 200) AS excerpt FROM table WHERE id = 1;
```

The important part is the `LEFT(...) AS excerpt`. Is there some sort of function (left() doesn't exist) which allows such selections? If not, how do I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution. If there's a neater way of doing this, please let me know, otherwise I'll stay with the following piece of code:

```
Post::select(DB::raw('LEFT(title, 200) AS excerpt'))->get();
```

`Post` is the name of an Eloquent model.